# In myosin II are regulatory and essential light chains calcium binding proteins or sites of phosphorylation?

Tags: cell-biology, proteins, muscles

According to my [medical physiology](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=1kGcFOKCUzkC&pg=PA140&lpg=PA140&dq=the%20essential%20light%20chain%20is%20necessary%20for%20myosin%20stability,%20and%20the%20other%20chain%20called%20the%20regulatory%20light%20chain%20is%20phosphorylated%20during%20muscle%20activity%20and%20serves%20to%20modulate%20muscle%20function&source=bl&ots=5qPEgK5qnX&sig=14S8Ks1fKKy3BhLxqbmZXmqyVYo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiTz-y-3pbVAhUEl5QKHTaZCiIQ6AEIMzAC#v=onepage&q=the%20essential%20light%20chain%20is%20necessary%20for%20myosin%20stability%2C%20and%20the%20other%20chain%20called%20the%20regulatory%20light%20chain%20is%20phosphorylated%20during%20muscle%20activity%20and%20serves%20to%20modulate%20muscle%20function&f=false) by Rhodes and Bell their description is as follows:

> the essential light chain is necessary for myosin stability, and the other chain called the regulatory light chain is phosphorylated during muscle activity and serves to modulate muscle function*

However, according to [molecular biology 4th edition:](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK21724/)

it states that the light chains both exert their function via Calcium binding, they make no mention of phosphorylation.

So do light chains regulate myosin by calcium binding, phosphorylation or both ?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is both, the regulatory light chains , regulate myosin by phosphorylation which  can be dependent or independent of $\ce{Ca^2+}$.

[Medical Physiology:](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=HlMJRw08ihgC&pg=PT706&lpg=PT706&dq=The%20activity%20of%20the%20myosin%20regulatory%20light%20chain%20is%20in%20turn%20regulated%20through%20phosphorylation%20by&source=bl&ots=2IWD_Gl82I&sig=OrRaXuAK33AgYYqJco3rIrihNRs&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjX3N2F2ZbVAhVEFpQKHUb4D24Q6AEIYTAJ#v=onepage&q=The%20activity%20of%20the%20myosin%20regulatory%20light%20chain%20is%20in%20turn%20regulated%20through%20phosphorylation%20by&f=false)

> The activity of the myosin regulatory light chain is in turn regulated through phosphorylation by $\ce{Ca^2+}$ -dependent and $\ce{Ca^2+}$ -independent kinases.

[Source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/11563549) claiming calcium is essential for phosphorylation in tarantula skeletal muscle:

> Contraction is modulated in many striated muscles by $\ce{Ca^2+}$-calmodulin dependent phosphorylation of the myosin regulatory light chain (RLC) by myosin light chain kinase.

Calcium independent phosphorylation of regulatory protein by [MLCK4:](http://www.pnas.org/content/113/27/E3824.abstract)

> We find that MLCK4 is also expressed abundantly in cardiac muscle, and structural analyses indicate that it is a $\ce{Ca^2+}$/calmodulin (CaM)-independent kinase, in contrast to $\ce{Ca^2+}$/CaM-stimulated cMLCK.

Comment: thank you for the answer! Does the calcium binding and/ or phosphorylation change the confirmation so as to modify the ATPase or the actin binding site ?

Comment: Read the section below figure 11.27 at https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK9961/